# Weird Array Creation in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, scope

I was reading the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for mysqli_stmt_bind_result and saw this code in the [comments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#100879):

```
while ( $field = $meta->fetch_field() ) {
  $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
}
```

given that neither $params nor $row existed before that line, why/how does that line work?

Comment: Sorry, I linked to the wrong wrong manual page. Links are fixed now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP doesn't actually have variable declaration. That means in some cases you can reference variables without actually having them declared beforehand. I say some cases because:

```
foreach($undefinedArray as $key=>$value){
    // will give a notice and a warning
    // notice: undefined variable
    // warning: invalid argument to foreach
}
```

But this doesn't mean you can't do something like so:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    $undefinedArray[]=$i;
}
// will create an array with 5 indexes, each holding the numbers 0 through 4
```

This works because `$undefinedArray` is not found and created on the fly.

Now, regarding your own case. I'm gonna assume you mean [this post](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#85470). And I have to admit, that's a very interesting solution, I'm gonna try to restrain myself from commenting on any kind of bad practice there, but let's get on to explaining it!

```
$params[] = &$row[$field->name];
```

This is where the magic happens and it's actually due to the &. Because `&$row['unknown_index']`, actually **creates** the index!

This means that above statement does 2 things. First it creates an array with each column name saved as an index in `$row` (`$row[$field->name]`). Then it saves a pointer to each of the elements from `$row` in `$params`.

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
```

This does `$stmt->bind_result()`. But passes each of the elements in `$params` as parameters to bind_result. And since they're passed by reference, each index of $row will hold each of the selected fields.

The rest should be easy to figure out now.

If you got any questions. Feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks! But why does the author create 2 arrays there? Wouldn't just doing $row[$field->name] suffice? (Actually I meant http://de2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#100879 (didn't know I could diretly link to comments), but they're the same code...)

Comment: Because he wants to use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) which passes each index of the array as parameters to the function. It's just easier to pass a non-fixed number of parameters via that function and he also needs each index to be a variable that won't clash (namely `$row`). Hard to explain in this comment. If you still don't get it, I'll reconsider updating my post :)

Comment: Yes, I understand why call_user_func_array() is being used. But what do you mean by clash?

Comment: I'm referring to the scope of variables, just having `$row[$field->name]` can clash with other variables in the same scope.

Answer (score 4):

From the first comment.

```
    $variables = array();
    $data = array();
    $meta = $result->result_metadata();

    while($field = $meta->fetch_field())
        $variables[] = &$data[$field->name]; // pass by reference

    call_user_func_array(array($result, 'bind_result'), $variables);
```

So what's the problem?

Comment: You are looking at the wrong comment. Sorry I didn't link to it in the first place. In the comment I meant $data didn't exist before calling it in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because as you said, these variables do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Being from C,C++ school of programming, i sometimes struggle to come to terms with PHP's stack and heap management. PHP does way too many things automatically, which gives way too much freedom to developers. Anyways, am sure [Dexter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345299/dexter) has got his doubts cleared after that wonderful explanation from [Khez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/688411/khez). I just want to add my cents in the code to make more sense of whats happening in the code mentioned [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#85470).

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT * FROM sample");
$stmt->execute ();
$meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

$params  = array (); // You can skip these lines, PHP initiates arrays on
$row     = array (); // the fly. I prefer doing as much of these initializations
$results = array (); // as possible, on my own.

while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
{
    /* Again, you can skip the following line, PHP will automatically create
     * a new key/value pair and since we are using the same name for the
     * container of that key/value pair, PHP will actually keep appending. 
     * So after N loops you have an array that contains N key/value pairs
     */
    $row [$field->name] = 0;

    $params[] =& $row[$field->name];
}

/* So now, $params is an array of N references, where reference i points to 
 * the value part of i-th key/val pair in $row 
 */

call_user_func_array (array ($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
$index = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch ())
{
    // again, one can skip this. PHP creates this on the fly.
    $results[$index] = array();
    foreach ($row as $key => $val)
    {
        // skip making that temp array!
        $results[$index][$key] = $val;
    }

    $index += 1;
}

return $results;
```

So that's it. Hopefully this code will make sense.

P.S: As an afterthought, I want to clarify one of my doubts regarding PHP. If I try to populate $results as below:

```
$results[$index][] = $row;
```

Or like this:

```
$results[] = $row;
```

All sets of key/value pairs in $results contain the same set repeatedly. Hopefully somebody and throw some light on this behavior of PHP.

[php-5.3](/questions/tagged/php-5.3) [mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli)